# Why am I getting the error message `" for writing : Invalid argument` when running a shell script in Cygwin under Windows 10?

Tags: cygwin

I wrote the following shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
dot -Tpng tp2.dot -o tp2.png
```

and saved it as `tp2.sh`. Then I ran `chmod u+x tp2.sh` under Cygwin.

When I run `./tp2.sh` I am getting the error

```
" for writing : Invalid argument
```

[image: Screenshot]

`tp2.dot` contains following text:

```
digraph G {
  graph [fontname = "Courier Prime"];
  node [fontname = "Courier Prime", shape=box];
  edge [fontname = "Courier Prime"];

  e1 [label="Start"]
}
```

`file tp2.dot` returns `tp2.dot: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`.

**What is causing the error when running `./tp2.sh` in a Cygwin window under Windows 10 and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Possible workaround: https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/Graphviz/v2.42.2.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the

> tp2.dot: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

convert the file from Windows CRLF format to Unix LF format with

```
 $ d2u tp2.dot
```

about the output in a specific file you need to use

```
$ dot -Tpng tp2.dot > tp2.png
```

or

```
$ dot -Tpng tp2.dot -O
```

the second case will add the `.png` to the source file name

```
$ ls -l tp2*
-rw-r--r-- 1 Marco Kein  159 Jan 22 15:08 tp2.dot
-rw-r--r-- 1 Marco Kein 1.4K Jan 22 15:13 tp2.dot.png
```